# Adding symbols to json Python

Tags: python, json

I was getting from website a json with tags.

```
['adventure in the comments', 'artist:s.guri', 'clothes', 'comments locked down', 'dashie slippers', 'edit', 'fractal', 'no pony', 'recursion', 'safe', 'simple background', 'slippers', 'tanks for the memories', 'the ride never ends', 'transparent background', 'vector', 'wat', 'we need to go deeper']
```

And i want to print it more or less like that

```
#adventureinthecomments #artist:s.guri #clothes #commentslockeddown #dashie #slippers #edit #fractal #nopony #recursion
```

Does somebody knows what method i need to use to remove all comas an add hashtag before word?
P.S Using Python 3

Comment: You can directly read the json list one by one. Then, add the # while printing

Comment: This is very easy, show us what code you've tried (Python 2 or 3?). Look at `string.join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways is to join to the single string with '#' and strip all white spaces and replace '#' with ' #' (with space)

```
arr = ['adventure in the comments', 'artist:s.guri', 'clothes', 'comments locked down', 'dashie slippers', 'edit', 'fractal', 'no pony', 'recursion', 'safe', 'simple background', 'slippers', 'tanks for the memories', 'the ride never ends', 'transparent background', 'vector', 'wat', 'we need to go deeper']

s= "#"
res = '#' + s.join(arr)

newVal = res.replace(' ','')
newNew = newVal.replace('#', ' #')
print(newNew)
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the rule for split the original sentences?, because the first one looks like
 'adventure in the comments' = '#adventureinthecomments'
but 
 'comments locked down' is splitted to #comments #locked #down
?

If there is no rules this could works

```
>>> jsontags = ['adventure in the comments', 'artist:s.guri', 'clothes', 'comments locked down', 'dashie slippers', 'edit', 'fractal', 'no pony', 'recursion', 'safe', 'simple background', 'slippers', 'tanks for the memories', 'the ride never ends', 'transparent background', 'vector', 'wat', 'we need to go deeper']
>>> '#'+' #'.join([tag.replace(' ','') for tag in jsontags])
```

This will be the result

```
'#adventureinthecomments #artist:s.guri #clothes #commentslockeddown #dashieslippers #edit #fractal #nopony #recursion #safe #simplebackground #slippers #tanksforthememories #therideneverends #transparentbackground #vector #wat #weneedtogodeeper'
```